# How do I fix or connect (checkbox) buttons together as to resist shifting when viewing on different browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, browser

```js
<td>
  <ul id="defects-pentagon">
  
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Defects" id="Taily" className="defect-taily" value="Taily"/>
       <label for="Taily">Taily</label>
       <div className="defect-taily-pentagon"></div>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Defects" id="Tapered" className="defect-tapered" value="Tapered"/>
      <label for="Tapered">Tapered</label>
      <div className="defect-tapered-pentagon"></div>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Defects" id="Curvy" className="defect-curvy" value="Curvy"/>
      <label for="Curvy">Curvy</label>
      <div className="defect-curvy-pentagon"></div>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Defects" id="Bumpy" className="defect-bumpy" value="Bumpy"/>
      <label for="Bumpy">Bumpy</label>
      <div className="defect-bumpy-pentagon"></div>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Defects" id="Irregular" className="defect-irregular" value="Irregular"/>
      <label for="Irregular">Irregular</label>
      <div className="defect-irregular-pentagon"></div>
    </li>
  </ul> 
</td>
```

```css
.defect-taily-pentagon {
    width:.3rem;
    height:4.7rem;
    background:#d70022;

    position: relative;
    transform: rotate(56deg);
    top: -90%;
    left: 100%;
}

.defect-tapered-pentagon {
    width:.3rem;
    height:4.7rem;
    background:#d70022;

    position: relative;
    transform: rotate(-56deg);
    top: -90%;
    right: -50%
}

.defect-curvy-pentagon {
    width:.3rem;
    height:4.5rem;
    background:#d70022;

    position: relative;
    transform: rotate(-19deg);
    top: -100%;
    left: 85%;
}

.defect-bumpy-pentagon {
    width:.3rem;
    height:4.5rem;
    background:#d70022;

    position: relative;
    transform: rotate(19deg);
    top: -100%;
    right: -66%;
}

.defect-irregular-pentagon {
    width:.3rem;
    height:4.5rem;
    background:#d70022;

    position: relative;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    top: -155%;
    left: 75%;
}
```

I am attempting to create a pentagon in css where each edge is a checkbox button. I have created the 5 buttons and changed their size to small, thin rectangles. Using rem units I was able to rotate and position each button so that they form a pentagon shape. However, when shrinking/growing my browser window, the buttons shift around.

I am looking for a way I can attach each button together and move the entire object as one unit to position it on my webpage. I believe the problem lies in the usage of the rem units and % units since they are relative to the entire browser size and not the size of the divider they're in.

The code is the same for each button except the id/className/label and the position (top/left) relative on the page.

**JavaScript**

```
<li> 
    <input type="checkbox"
     id="Taily"
     className="defect-taily"/>
     
     <label for="Taily"> Taily </label>    
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.defect-taily-pentagon {
  width:.3rem;
  height:4.7rem;
  background:#d70022;

  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(56deg);
  top: -90%;
  left: 100%;
}
```

P.S. I am unable to post a picture since this is my first post on stackoverflow. When I am able, I will post an image.

Comment: You are right that using % in that way won’t work. Investigate using vmin as a unit instead.

Comment: Could you add a working snippit to your question?

Comment: Include all the code you're using to create the pentagon using the snippet editor please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking you may want to put all of your buttons inside a div (like a container) and experiment positioning them with `position: absolute;` relative to the div `position: relative;`. This way you will only need to style the div to adapt to different devices.

This is a code snippet, have a look:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html{width: 100%; font-size: 10px; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
            body{width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
            .container{
                min-width: 250px; width: 100%; min-height: 200px; height: 100%; position: relative; padding: 0; margin: 0;
                background-image: radial-gradient(at 50% 50%, hsl(209, 64%, 61%), hsl(226, 100%, 13%));
                /* background-image: radial-gradient(at 35% -15%, var(--med ), var(--darker), var(--darkgris) 70%, var(--darkpurple)) */
            }
            .bg-black{
                border-radius: 5rem; height: 5rem; width: 5rem;
                background-image: radial-gradient(at -50% 100%, hsl(0, 0%, 100%), hsl(0, 0%, 0%));
            }
            .container>div:nth-child(1){position: absolute; left: calc(50% - 5rem /2); top: 0;}
            .container>div:nth-child(2){position: absolute; left: calc(100% - 5rem); top: calc(25% - 5rem /2);}
            .container>div:nth-child(3){position: absolute; left: calc(75% - 5rem /2); top: calc(100% - 5rem);}
            .container>div:nth-child(4){position: absolute; left: calc(25% - 5rem /2); top: calc(100% - 5rem);}
            .container>div:nth-child(5){position: absolute; left: 0; top: calc(25% - 5rem /2);}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="bg-black"></div>
            <div class="bg-black"></div>
            <div class="bg-black"></div>
            <div class="bg-black"></div>
            <div class="bg-black"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```